# Insert into table without values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have a table with a primary key, 9 NOT NULL fields and 15 ALLOW NULL fields.

How do I insert a row in the table without having to explicitly set the values for the 9 fields?

Comment: You define the table to have default values for those columns.  Otherwise you have to specify something.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Note that you should only define a default if there is a reasonable one. If you really need all those fields specified, then you absolutely should *not* have a default. In which case, you should grin and bear it and specify them. In my experience, reasonable defaults are hard to come by.

Comment: @jpmc26 I tend to agree and shy away from them. I find that replying upon them tends to cause people to forget that those fields are there or consider their initial values when updating the system in a way that might invalidate the default (i.e. no longer reasonable). And so I tend to use them mostly for setting CreatedOn/ModifiedOn audit fields. BUT, there are situations where they are helpful and people should know how to interact with them (hence my answer). For example, creating test tables with defaults makes it easy to generate rows while only dealing with fields needing varying values.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have defaults created for those 9 `NOT NULL` fields, you have three options:

- Don't set values for any field by using `DEFAULT VALUES`.
- Don't set values for the `NOT NULL` fields by simply not specifying those fields in the INSERT column list or VALUES list.
- Don't set values for the `NOT NULL` fields, assuming they *are* specified in the INSERT column list, by using the `DEFAULT` keyword instead of a value.

Example showing each option as well as the effect of explicitly inserting a `NULL` into a NULLable field that has a default:

```sql
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
  ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  NotNullField DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
  NullableFieldWithDefault DATETIME NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
  NullableFieldWithNoDefault DATETIME NULL
);

-- No values specified for any fields
INSERT INTO @Test DEFAULT VALUES;

-- Values specified only for NULLable field with no default
INSERT INTO @Test (NullableFieldWithNoDefault) VALUES ('2112-12-21');

-- DEFAULT keyword used for fields with a default
INSERT INTO @Test (NotNullField, NullableFieldWithDefault, NullableFieldWithNoDefault)
VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, '1999-03-15');

-- NULLs specified for NULLable fields
INSERT INTO @Test (NullableFieldWithDefault, NullableFieldWithNoDefault)
VALUES (NULL, NULL);


SELECT * FROM @Test;
```

Results:

```
ID  NotNullField              NullableFieldWithDefault   NullableFieldWithNoDefault
--  -----------------------   ------------------------   --------------------------
1   2015-01-11 16:22:31.317   2015-01-11 16:22:31.317    NULL
2   2015-01-11 16:22:31.320   2015-01-11 16:22:31.320    2112-12-21 00:00:00.000
3   2015-01-11 16:22:31.320   2015-01-11 16:22:31.320    1999-03-15 00:00:00.000
4   2015-01-11 16:22:31.320   NULL                       NULL
```